# Pitfalls for breaking up a large file into one DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, multiple-inheritance, dllexport

I am not that experienced in creating DLL's in MSVC++ 2010, just may be a few times as part of the learning curve. At the moment I have a very large file with about 10 different classes in it. I have to breakdown the file into multiple files and move out related classes to the same file. So before proceeding wanted to know from experienced developers about my situation.

Something like the following

```
// Header
namespace collections
{
 classA
 classB
 ClassC
 ClassD : ClassA,ClassB
}
// CPP
namespace collections
{
 classA
  {
      // Implementations
  }
 // Rest of the classes
}
```

After breaking down to separate files

```
// ClassA.h
namespace Collections
{
  ClassA
}

// ClassB.h
namespace Collections
{
  ClassB
}

// Implentations etc
```

My main concern is the usage of dllexport/dllimport storage class attributes
Since The file will be broken up I would have to use the following

```
#ifdef MAKEDLL
#  define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

against the classes to export/import them. But placing these line in each header file that will be create (with one namespace "Collections"), will this have any bad implications while compiling or code generation step? I was looking around on-line and found out that people most complain about linker errors/warnings where a particular member is redefined or is not found whilst creating DLL's. This must definitely be a solved issue just that I dont know which is the best and proper way of doing it.
I need to create just one DLL in the end. I dont need to create multiple DLL's.

Any guidance or help is much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: first thing, you should not dll separate classes that share a logic context ( are responsible for some sort of the same thing ). If your classes are written well and not in the same file ( I read that lines that you have all classes in ONE source file? ) that should not be an issue. IMHO splitting them in different dlls, only makes sense if you want to deliver your programm with different functionality (plugins), but if your programm always requires all of the dlls to work, you can plainly let them be as they are now.

Comment: Your question is unclear about whether you want to split one DLL into several, or one H/CC file into several while keeping them into one DLL.

Comment: @Najzero The file is getting a big mess. So I have to break it down

Comment: @MatthieuRouget Edited the question and yes I need one DLL

Comment: @Wajih: OK, so my answer should help you.

Comment: You clean up a "big mess" by focusing on the source code, not the way it gets compiled and linked.  There otherwise isn't any real question here.  Get it done, come back when you have a real problem instead of an imaginary one.

Comment: @HansPassant - You missed the point, as I said I am not the experienced so I needed some guidance before I push myself into more pitfalls. I did not ask for a fix. So you are wrong. Does stackoverflow say that we can't ask for guidance from experienced people prior to touching the code?

Comment: @Wajih It think that Hans said that you should have tried to get the things done by yourself before posting here. In general, for small scale issues like yours, the "_So before proceeding wanted to know from experienced developers about my situation._" strategy is not the way to go when learning how to developp software.. because _try, fail, retry, refail, retry, success_ is a very good way to learn :)

Comment: @Mathieu Well I dont disagree with him completely but my point was to gain some more knowledge. I guess I am at the wrong site :) And I know its try and fail and try retry and so on and so forth. But anyways. Well everyone has a write to express their opinion

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue to have one common header file that defines the `EXPORTS` macro:

**mydll.h**

```
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

And have this header file included in other header files:

**ClassA.h**

```
#include "mydll.h"
namespace Collections
{
  class MYDLL_API ClassA {
    // ...
  }
}
```

**ClassA.cpp**

```
#include "ClassA.h"
// ...
```

**ClassB.h**

```
#include "mydll.h"
namespace Collections
{
  class MYDLL_API ClassB {
    // ...
  }
}
```

... and so on. You can have all of them (header files and .cpp implementation files) in one DLL, having `MYDLL_EXPORTS` defined in your DLL project settings (it is automatically done by the VS2010 DLL wizard).

There is nothing weird here. You never redefine anything. 
You just use the handy `MYDLL_API` to add a decorator to all your DLL API classes.

Comment: @Mathieu So I keep the EXPORT macros in one common header file and then use them in the rest of the header files. Despite all of this, will there be any issues the sequence in which I split the files and include them? Like Class1 consumes an object of class2

Comment: @Mathieu I will check this and see if I can select your answer!

Comment: No, the fact that files are in DLL does not change anything compared to being in a program. If your classes have some dependencies between them, say `ClassB` needs `ClassA` then you should `#include "ClassA.h"` in `ClassB.h`. If you have cyclic dependencies, use forward declaration, as usual (and as you need if all your declarations are in the same file).

Comment: @Mathieu Thanks I will have to spend some time on this and get back